# Sending variable from one ajax call to the next

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have an API I'm trying to query which requires an initial request to generate the report, it returns a report ID and then in 5 seconds you can pull it from that report ID.

This is what I have which works perfectly and returns the reportID:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#r2").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
        url: "report.php", 
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { 
            type: 'queue', 
            ref: 2
        },
        success: function(result){
            console.log(result.reportID);
        }});
    });
});
```

It returns this:

```
{"reportID":1876222901}
```

I'm trying to make it call another ajax call on the back of the first one to collect the report using the reportID as the data varaible "ref". So for example, the second ajax query should have `ref: 1876222901`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#r2").click(function(){
        $('#loading').show();
        $.ajax({
        url: "report.php", 
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { 
            type: 'queue', 
            ref: 2
        },
        success: function(result){
            console.log(result);
            $.ajax({
            url: "report.php", 
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { 
            type: 'get', 
            ref: result.reportID
            },
            success: function(result){
                console.log(result);
            }
            });
        }});
    });
});
```

What I am stuck with is the way I am passing the variable from the result of the first ajax call to the second. It doesn't seem to make it there. How should I send my report ID `1876222901` into my second ajax call please?

Comment: "What I am stuck with is the way I am passing the variable from the result of the first ajax call to the second." — Looks fine to me

Comment: "It doesn't seem to make it there" — What are you doing to determine this?

Comment: Agree with Quentin, this looks like it should work. side note, if possible check out promises as an alternative technique for handling this type of scenario https://github.com/axios/axios

Comment: If `console.log(result.reportID);` is printing `{"reportID":1876222901}` then you need to use `result.reportID.reportID` to access the value or are you expecting `ref` to be an object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this without jQuery just using browser built-in DOM APIs and the fetch API

```
const r2 = document.getElementById('r2')
const loading = document.getElementById('loading')

const handleAsJson = response => response.json()

const fetchRef = ({reportId}) =>
  fetch(`report.php?type=get&ref=${reportId}`)

document.onready = () => {
  r2.addEventListener('click', () => {
    loading.show();
    // you don't have to interpolate here, but in case these
    // values are variable...
    fetch(`report.php?type=${'queue'}&ref=${2}`)
      .then(handleAsJson)
      .then(fetchRef)
      .then(handleAsJson)
      .then(console.log)
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is instead of writing

`ref: result.reportID`

You have to write it like this

`ref: result.reportID.reportID`

Because as your said, the first time you use `console.log(result.reportID)` the result is `{"reportID":1876222901}`. Which means you have to chaining dot notation twice to be able to reach the value `1876222901` in the next ajax call.

To be clear:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#r2").click(function(){
        $('#loading').show();
        $.ajax({
        url: "report.php", 
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { 
            type: 'queue', 
            ref: 2
        },
        success: function(result){
            console.log(result); // as you said, console.log(result.reportID) return {"reportID":1876222901}
            $.ajax({
              url: "report.php", 
              dataType: 'json',
              data: { 
              type: 'get', 
              ref: result.reportID //which means, this line would be => ref: {"reportID":1876222901}
              // we will correct it like this => ref: result.reportID.reportID
              // then we properly get => ref:1876222901
            },
            success: function(result){ 
                console.log(result); 
            }
            });
        }});
    });
});
```

Hopefully it fixes your error.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try to make another function for calling after your first ajax like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#r2").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
        url: "report.php", 
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { 
            type: 'queue', 
            ref: 2
        },
        success: function(result){
            console.log(result.reportID);
            callSecondAjax(result.reportID)
        }});
    });
});
```

now make that function like

```
function callSecondAjax(reportId){
// do some stuff 
}
```